# Rails - Doing simple division? Not so simple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in a controller:

```
  @users = User.order("created_at").all
  @user_count = @users.length.to_i
  @active_7_day = .....count.to_i

  @mystat = (@user_count / @active_7_day)
```

No errors which is nice, but in the view @mystat is always 0? How do you do division in Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result is probably a float.

```
@mystat = (@user_count.to_f / @active_7_day)
```

Comment: How do you round that to two decimals? round_to and round_at both error?

Comment: Round it in the view: `number_with_precision(@mystat, :precision => 2)`